# Find the centre Z(ML(2;integers) of this group

Tags: matrices, group-theory

ML(2;Z)=all matrices (a,b,c,d): a,b,c,d are integers and ad-bc=1or-1

Find the centre of this group.

Okay so I know elements commute so AB=BA and i've let A=(a1,a2,a3,a4) B=(b1,b2,b3,b4) then done matrix mult and equated entries which was right from my answer solutions.

But then it says choose b1=-b4=1 and b2=b3=0. How do we know to choose this?

Answer (score 2):

The group $G$ is called $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and its center is the subgroup of the scalar matrices whose scalar entries are $\pm 1$. This follows directly from the calculation. If we fix some $A$ with $A\in Z(G)$, then we can choose suitable $B$ with $AB=BA$ to obtain conditions for $A$, because we have $AB=BA$ for all $B\in G$ by the definition of the center.
In general, for a commutative ring $R$, the group $GL_n(R)$ has center $Z$ consisting of the subgroup of all scalar matrices whose scalar entry is an invertible element of $R$.